# Варенье. Корень вар, а суффикс [ен"j]?

Tags: словообразование

*Варенье*. Корень *-вар-*, а суффикс [ен"j]? Сомнения в том, что не произошло ли здесь сращения этимологических суффикса и корня: корень[варен"J], окончание [э]-[а]-[у] и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В Словообразовательном словаре Тихонова в слове **варенье** однозначно выделяется корень вар-, суффикс -ен'j- и окончание. Никакого сращения нет.